# how to display the name values based on dropdown value using typescript in angular?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular

I want to get the dropdown name into in header as welcome {{something}} like this but i can't able to do so. any help would be helpful.
In .ts

```
public accountledger: Observable<Account>;

 this._journalvoucherService.getAccounts().subscribe(data => { this.accountledger = data });
```

In .html

```
 <p *ngIf="accounts"></p> {{accounts?.Name}} Account Ladger View
```

Comment: where is dropdown code?

Comment: Right now as i'm understanding you're assign the data to accountledger. But you want to show the variable accounts. Those are two different variables

Comment: Dropdown list is in grid/table. i want to show dropdown value name into header like welcome {{name}}. did you have any clue?

Comment: <p *ngIf="accountledger"></p> {{accountledger?.Name}} Account Ladger View too not working. since accounts is used for dropdown list.